# crond high cpu usage

Tags: docker, cron, linode

So today I noticed a interesting "crond" process taking up 100% of the cpu.

The strange thing is, I don't have cron installed.

```
find / -name "crond"
/var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/d359c68dd07e2defb573e3d6f5c20f9984a3796d1fbdd92dd2d48923bf49ea8f/rootfs/usr/sbin/crond
```

Not really sure what else I can do besides kill the process. Is there any way I could diagnose the cause of this issue?

Comment: Do you mean you don't have cron installed into your host OS?
Did you tried giving a look to the logs *within* the container?

Comment: I don't know which container it is.

Comment: Do you have a lot of containers running? If you have only a few containers running, issuing `docker inspect <container> | grep d359c68dd07e2defb573e3d6f5c20f9984a3796d1fbdd92dd2d48923bf49ea8f` you should get a match for the container you are looking for.
probably there are easier ways to get the same.

Comment: Thanks for that, it seems to be the nginx:alpine container.

Comment: Glad to know you found it.
Any clue on root cause from logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *crond* is running within the container.

You can attach to the container, i.e. with `docker exec -it <container> bash` then navigate to `/var/logs` and inspect logs for further analysis.

In case you have multiple running containers you need to find which one is generating the issue: i.e. you can enumerate them with `docker ps` then run 
`docker inspect <container> | grep d359c68dd07e2defb573e3d6f5c20f9984a3796d1fbdd92dd2d48923bf49‌​ea8f` on each.

When you have a hit you have found the container to analyze further.